# Spring Data Repository on same Entity class name, but different package

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two entity classes that have the same name, but they are in different packages, and have different Id.

```
package sample.visa;

@Entity
@Table(name="APP_VISA")
public class Application
{
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    ...
}
```

```
package sample.student;

@Entity
@Table(name="APP_STU")
public class Application
{
    @Id
    private String studentId;
    ...
}
```

Then, I have a Spring Data repository to retrieve from one of the entity class.

```
package sample.student;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface ApplicationRepository extends CrudRepository<sample.student.Application, String>
{   
}
```

When I tried to call the find method (e.g. findById) in the injected repository, I supposed it should have queried the database table APP_STU. However, it actually queried APP_VISA and returned the following error message.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: studentId of: sample.visa.Application
```

Is there any way to make the repository targeting to the APP_STU instead? Or renaming the class is the only way to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to have duplicate name for two different Entities for one Project even the entities reside in two different packages.

Entity names must be unique. When two entity classes in different packages share the same class name, explicit entity name setting is required to avoid collision

[Reference](https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/types#Entity_Classes_)

Comment: In JPQL, I can explicitly specifies the full class name (e.g. SELECT obj FROM sample.visa.Application obj WHERE obj.id = ? ") to let JPA query the correct table. So I just wonder whether it is possible when using Spring Data. But seems using different class names is the best way to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

Just rename that class, i think you can't use two classes (entities) with the same name. Try to rename it, and call it again, should work :)